# Rail&Fly: where to buy the reservation for City Night Line trains at Deutsche Bahn?

Tags: trains, tickets, germany, bookings, night-transport

I have a plane ticket including a [rail@fly ticket](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail&Fly) for the Deutsche Bahn (DB). I want to use a [City Night Line train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_Night_Line), which has a **compulsory reservation**.

But where can I find this reservation option? I’ve read in many places that I have to go to www.bahn.de, but that is not very detailed. I cannot find an option to insert my rail@fly ticket and only pay for the reservation.

How do I have to do this?

Comment: For future readers: this question is now only of historical interest, as the City Night Line no longer exists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question relates to a train that no longer exists.  This question is of historical interest only.

Answer (score 6):

On the [home page](http://www.bahn.de/i/view/USA/en/index.shtml) add the route and time you are going to travel. Click Search. On the 'Select' step, there is a button 'Change Query' below the connections, click it, this brings you to a bigger form which towards the bottom has 'Reservation for seat only (no ticket)' tick that. Pick your train and go for 'Reversation'. You can then book without registering and pick your seat/berth. I don't think you need to enter the ticket number as long as it is the same train you should be fine.

Comment: Note that this only works if your journey either stars or ends in Germany.  Some CityNightLine trains, such as Amsterdam–Copenhagen or Basel–Copenhagen, have both end-points outside Germany.  For travel between those end-points, a "reservation only" tickets are not available through the DB website.

Comment: I’ve done the steps that Peter suggested. But the reservation column states »No reservation possible«. I want to use this train: http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/traininfo.exe/dn/894519/509386/649440/26547/80?ld=96243&seqnr=5&ident=6o.022425243.1382944561&date=11.11.13&station_evaId=8000261&station_type=dep&currentReferrer=tp&rt=1& which in contrast to what gerrit said, has both start and destination in Germany.

Comment: You cannot book trains with compulsory reservation this way. You will have to contact DB directly (click on "contact" on the website)

Comment: Krist van Besien, can you make your comment an answer and I will accept it the answer to my question. Thank you. I called DB and made a reservation. But even the person on the phone didn’t know of that limitation. Do you have a source for this?

Answer (score 3):

First go to http://citynightline.de and click on the map to start the query. Enter the stop at which you want to enter the night train and the one at which you want to get off the train. Then click "search". When you found your night train, click on "check availability". A price list will appear with the regular prices. Since you have a rail&fly ticket already, you can click onto "Book only extra charge" next to the regular booking button. The web site will ask you if you have a "pass" or a "normally priced ticket". No clue which is the correct one here. At the end of the booking process, you can enter your credit card information and will receive a PDF with the ticket that you need to print out.